# Swagger editor and session cookies

Tags: session-cookies, swagger-editor

According to [this document](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/cookie-authentication/), I could use:

```
components:
  securitySchemes:
    cookieAuth:
      type: apiKey
      in: cookie
      name: JSESSIONID
```

To define a `session cookie`. But if you go to [the editor](https://editor.swagger.io) to change line 577 from `in: "header"` to `in: "cookie"`, the editor blames with:

> Schema error at `securityDefinitions['api_key'].in` should be equal to
>   one of the allowed values allowedValues: `header`, `query`.

How must I define a session cookie based auth?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cookie authentication is an OpenAPI 3.0 feature and is not supported in OpenAPI 2.0. Your spec is OpenAPI 2.0, as indicated by `securityDefinitions`. You can't mix 2.0 and 3.0 syntax. You'll need to rewrite or convert your spec to the OpenAPI 3.0 format.

That said, cookie authentication is currently [not supported](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-js/issues/1163) in Swagger UI and Swagger Editor - but is supported in SwaggerHub.